# NewRelic insights dashboard api

Tags: api, azure-application-insights, dashboard, newrelic, newrelic-platform

Please help me to create a insights dashboard in NewRelic with error HTTP/1.1 0 error

I am trying to follow the steps as in NewRelic course upload json with minore changes like links and id . But still got error

Comment: You can refer to [HTTP/1.1 0 error Response received from API Explore when trying to create a Dashboard](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/http-1-1-0-error-response-received-from-api-explore-when-trying-to-create-a-dashboard/108920)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete documentation for insights on NewRelic dashboard api

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/explore-query-data/dashboards/dashboards-api/

Also you can check the link suggested by DeepDave,

https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/http-1-1-0-error-response-received-from-api-explore-when-trying-to-create-a-dashboard/108920